# Nonzero exit status : 216 (Pascal).. How can i fix this error?

Tags: freepascal

I tried everything : to change the data type, to initialize the variables before using them, but nothing worked, what is the problem?

```
Program Criptmat;
   type Matrice = array[1..20,1..20] of char;

    var x : Matrice;
     s,s1 : string;
      i,j,n,k,l : integer;
        f,f1 : text;

begin
 assign(f,'criptmat.in');
  reset(f);
   readln(f,n);
  readln(f,s);
 close(f);

   k:=1;
    l:=length(s) div n;

    for i:=1 to l do
     if i mod 2 = 1 then
      for j:=1 to n do  
        begin
          x[i,j]:=s[k];
         k:=k+1;
        end else
       if i mod 2 = 0 then
        for j:=n downto 1 do 
         begin
          x[i,j]:=s[k];
           k:=k+1;
         end;

     s1:='';

    for j:=1 to n do
     for i:=1 to l do
      s1:=s1+x[i,j];

 assign(f1,'criptmat.out');
  rewrite(f1);
   writeln(f1,s1);
  close(f1);
 end.
```

Please, help me to fix this error to avoid this kind of mistake in the future, thank you!

Comment: Please add the contents of your criptmat,in file to your q, because readers shouldn't have to guess this.  I run your code in Lazarus with a criptmat.in containing 20 followed by 'something' and it executes without any run-time error.

Comment: @MartynA Perhaps better if we teach the asker how to debug the errors, and then they never need to ask this question again

Comment: @DavidHeffernan.  Sure, I'm all for OPs learning to debug first rather than ask first, debug later.  However in this case the OP obviously hasn't provided full details of how to reproduce the error, which is a defect in the q imo.  Surely, it's better to get the OP to provide the details necessary *before* launching into possible causes and how to debug them?

Comment: @MartynA Not in my view. In my opinion, if the user hasn't yet learnt how to debug then it's counter productive for us to do the debugging for them. The user gets a fish, but tomorrow is still hungry, and needs another fish.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Well the world would be a dull place if we all agreed (etc).  If nothing else at least it ought to occur to the OP that the (mis)behaviour of a program conceivably depends on its input.

Answer (score 1):

Error 216 in fpc is an access violation or segment fault, depending on your preferred terminology. This happens when you try to access a memory address that is not valid. Typically that happens when you attempt to access an array outside of its bounds, or access dynamically allocated memory that has already been deallocated.

In your case it is likely that you are accessing the array out of bounds. Use the debugger to locate the point of failure, and inspect the value of your indices at that point of execution. This will tell you which access is invalid, and then you can set about fixing the logic errors that lead to the out of bounds access.

A useful tool to help such debugging is to enable the range checking compilation option. This will inject runtime code to validate every array access. You will find it much easier to debug these faults with that enabled.